# Sqlite onCreate isn't invoked after dropping/deleting the table from the database/storage

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```dart
class Helper {
  Database _db;

  Future<Database> initDb() async {
    if (_db == null) {
      final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      _db = await openDatabase(join(directory.path, 'foo.db'), version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    }
    return _db;
  }

  Future<void> _onCreate(Database db, _) async {
    print('onCreate');
    await db.transaction((txn) async {
      await txn.execute('CREATE TABLE tableName(abc TEXT)');
    });
  }
}
```

Here's my main method:

```dart
void main() async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  final file = File(join(directory.path, 'foo.db'));
  if (await file.exists()) {
    await file.delete();
  }

  // If there had been a file, it's deleted now.
  final helper = Helper();
  await helper.initDb(); // This must fire `onCreate` but it doesn't.
}
```

Every time you run the `main` method, it should execute the `onCreate` method in `Helper` class but it only does that once. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue description has changed since the beginning and it is not easy to make a proper explanation in a comment so here is yet another answer.

All existing responses remain valid but the issue now is moving to something like **onCreate not called after deleting the database**.

> Every time you run the main method, it should execute the onCreate method in Helper class but it only does that once. What am I doing wrong here?

You don't really specify how you run (i.e. do you stop the application before), so I'm assuming you are just pressing the run button on your IDE which performs a hot-restart.

While you might be enclined to simply delete the file, you should however use
`deleteDatabase` to properly delete a database.

```dart
// Do not call File.delete, it will not work in a hot restart scenario
await File(path).delete();

// Instead do
await deleteDatabase(path);
```

- it will properly close any existing database connection
- it will properly handle the hot-restart scenario which put `SQLite` in a
  weird state (basically the 'dart' side think the database is closed while
  the database is in fact open on the native side)

If you call `File.delete`, while you might think it work (i.e. the file does not
exist anymore), since the database might still be opened in a hot restart scenario
the next open will re-use the open connection and at some point will get written
with the old data and `onCreate` will not be called the next time you open
the database.

Comment: I forgot who I was talking to, the creator of the package, and I'll be very honest, I'm going to accept the answer before even reading what you wrote.

Comment: I am really sorry sir, your answer was the one I wanted to award bounty to, but in hurry I didn't noticed your answer was the one being selected and mistakenly the bounty has been rewarded to other user. I'll surely put a new bounty and award you.

Comment: Sir, a side question, is it recommended to drop the table before calling `deleteDatabase`?

Comment: there is no need to drop any table before deleting a database.

Comment: Got it sir, thank you so much. Awarding you bounty :)

Answer (score 3):

`onCreate` will be executed only when there is no database file. Not when there is no table in the db. If you delete database file then there will be a print in console with message `onCreate`. Here is an example:

```
void main() async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  final path = join(directory.path, 'foo.db');
  await File(path).delete();

  final helper = Helper();
  await helper.initDb();
  // await helper.dropTable();
}
```

This code prints a log message every run of a program.

Comment: Even after deleting the file, `onCreate` doesn't run

Comment: It's strange. I've checked the code before posting and it works. Maybe your problem somewhere else. Maybe deleting the file throws some error or something. Try to add print before calling `initDb` method in the main method. Are you testing on a device or on a emulator? Try to add prints to every line to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: My blunder, I thought the top answer would be from alextk and awarded bounty.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how Sqflite works.

The very first time when you create a database you give it a version number. In your case the version is 1.

Sqflite will check if database exists on the devices if it exists it checks the version number of db on device and version number of your code, if version is not the same it will call onUpgrade if new version is greater than old db version. and on downgrade if old version is greater than new version. OnCreate won't be called. onCreate is only called the very first time user install your app. Even if you drop your tables afterwards. If you need to update your database in future on a production app, you have to write onUpgrade method, in which you have to explicitly drop your tables and call onCreate yourself. and upgrade the database version.

See the following code. Use this code setup and change version to a higher version number whenever you need to dropAll tables and createAgain.

If you don't want to use the versions and explicitly drop tables and recreate them. You have to call _onCreate yourself after dropping a table.

```
class Helper {
  Database _db;

  Future<Database> initDb() async {
    if (_db == null) {
      final directory = await getDatabasesPath();
      final path = join(directory, 'foo.db');
      _db = await openDatabase(
        path,
        version: 2, //+1 to this number whenever you want to update 
        onCreate: _onCreate,
        onUpgrade: _onUpgrade,
      );
    }
    return _db;
  }

  Future<void> _onUpgrade(
      Database db, int previousVersion, int newVersion) async {
    _db = db;
    await dropTable();
    await _onCreate(db, newVersion);
  }

  Future<void> _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    print('onCreate');
    await db.transaction((txn) async {
      await txn.execute('CREATE TABLE tableName(abc TEXT)');
    });
  }

  Future<void> dropTable() async {
    await _db.transaction((txn) async {
      await txn.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tableName');
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the default behavior because onCreate Method is executed when you create the database. Since the database is created before it is not executed again.

If you intent to clean the rows of the table then use the TRUNCATE command. For more information check the link comparing drop table and truncate table [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_drop_table.asp)

Comment: Even if I delete the database using `File.delete` method, the `onCreate` doesn't get invoked.

Comment: Have you tried changing the version number. That should work.

Comment: Changing the version number enforces `onUpgrade` to get called which I don't want. I simply want to use things as the database was never created, i.e. a simple invocation of `onCreate` with version number `1`

Comment: @iDecode  run ```await helper.initDb();``` again.. after ```File.delete```

Comment: Don't use `File.delete` to delete a database, use `deleteDatabase` instead. As @morpheus said, `onCreate` is only called when the database does not exist.

Comment: @alextk Can you please run the code I showed in the post, you'll see the onCreate isn't getting called even when the file is deleted from the storage.

Comment: I created a separate answer (again: don't use `File.delete`)